# Special layout with multi-page table in ConTeXt

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I have a special layout of page to make. It contains blocks of text, a graph and tables. I don't know in advance the length of the tables in the document. I have a dummy two tables example to show what I want to do. 
[image: sample document]

And the code to do that is here:

```
    \setupcolors[state=start]
    \setuplayout[backspace=20mm,
    topspace=20mm,
    header=0mm, 
    footer=10mm,
    leftedge=0.5in,
    rightedge=0.5in,
    width=fit,
    rightmargin=0mm]

    \starttext

    \startuseMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}
    picture p ; numeric o ; path a, b ; pair c ;
    p := textext.rt(\MPstring{FunnyFrame}) ;
    o := BodyFontSize ;
    a := unitsquare xyscaled(OverlayWidth,OverlayHeight) ;
    pickup pencircle scaled OverlayLineWidth ;
    b := a  ;
    fill b withcolor .5[white, blue] ;
    draw b withcolor .5[white, blue] ;
    setbounds currentpicture to a ;
    \stopuseMPgraphic

    \defineoverlay[FunnyFrame][\useMPgraphic{FunnyFrame}]
    \defineblank[aroundFrame][1pt]
    \defineframedtext[FunnyText][frame=off,background=FunnyFrame,align={middle,hilo}, color=white,backgroundoffset=0pt,offset=3pt,width=\hsize,margin=no,before={\blank[aroundFrame]},after={\blank[aroundFrame]}]
    \def\StartFrame{\startFunnyText}
    \def\StopFrame {\stopFunnyText }
    \setMPtext{FunnyFrame}{} % initialize the text variable


    \defineparagraphs[DetailTablesColumns][n=2, distance=0pt, tolerance=very tolerant]
    \setupparagraphs[DetailTablesColumns][1][width=2.5cm]

    \setupTABLE[row][each][framecolor=white,rulethickness=2pt,frame=on]
    \setupTABLE[row][even]
    [background=color,backgroundcolor=white,frame=off]
    \setupTABLE[row][odd]
    [background=color,backgroundcolor=gray,frame=off]
    \setupTABLE[header][each]
    [background=color,backgroundcolor=darkblue,foregroundcolor=white,style=bold]
    \setupTABLE[column][each][width=.25\hsize]

    \startDetailTablesColumns
    \StartFrame[width=\hsize]
    Some funny title

    With subtitle
    \StopFrame
    \DetailTablesColumns
    \bTABLE[align=right,option=stretch,split=repeat]
    \bTABLEhead
    \bTR
    \bTH A1 \eTH \bTH B1 \eTH \bTH C1 \eTH \bTH D1 \eTH
    \eTR
    \eTABLEhead
    \bTABLEbody
    \dorecurse{3}
    {
    \bTR
    \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \bTD 4 \eTD
    \eTR
    }
    \eTABLEbody
    \eTABLE
    \stopDetailTablesColumns

    \startDetailTablesColumns
    \StartFrame[width=\hsize]
    Another funny title

    Still with subtitle
    \StopFrame
    \DetailTablesColumns
    \bTABLE[align=right,option=stretch,split=repeat]
    \bTABLEhead
    \bTR
    \bTH A \eTH \bTH B \eTH \bTH C \eTH \bTH D \eTH
    \eTR
    \eTABLEhead
    \bTABLEbody
    \dorecurse{26}
    {
    \bTR
    \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \bTD 4 \eTD
    \eTR
    }
    \eTABLEbody
    \eTABLE
    \stopDetailTablesColumns
    \startDetailTablesColumns
    \StartFrame[width=\hsize]
    Another funny title

    Still with subtitle
    \StopFrame
    \DetailTablesColumns
    \bTABLE[align=right,option=stretch]
    \bTABLEhead
    \bTR
    \bTH A \eTH \bTH B \eTH \bTH C \eTH \bTH D \eTH
    \eTR
    \eTABLEhead
    \bTABLEbody
    \dorecurse{24}
    {
    \bTR
    \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \bTD 4 \eTD
    \eTR
    }
    \eTABLEbody
    \eTABLE
    \stopDetailTablesColumns

    \stoptext
```

I would want to be able to define my table only once, as this is dynamically generated. Any idea ?

I used paragraphs because that seemed to work, but I'm open to trying something else if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Your code seems to work just fine.  Also this question is really old, so I'm voting to close as unclear.